# Custom rescorer on NativeSearchQuery

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

I installed a custom rescorer plugin on Elasticsearch but I couldn't find a way to call it by using ElasticsearchOperations.
I'm using the NativeSearchQuery built by a NativeSearchQueryBuilder but I could only find a method to add a QueryRescore and not a custom one.
Is there a way to use a custom rescorer plugin?

Comment: How would you call it in a direct call to Elasticsearch?

Comment: The direct call is like this:

`"query": {"match_all": {}},"rescore": {"<plugin-name>": {"<param-1>": "<param-1-value>","<param-2>": "<param-2-value>", ..., "<param-n>": "<param-n-value>"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I don't see such a possibility in the code of `org.elasticsearch.search.builder.SearchSourceBuilder`. There is the method `addRescorer(RescorerBuilder<?> rescoreBuilder)` but the only `RescorerBuilder` that Elasticsearch offers is the `org.elasticsearch.search.rescore.QueryRescorerBuilder`.

So for Spring Data Elasticsearch there is currently no way to add custom rescorers.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticserach offer the abstract *class org.elasticsearch.search.rescore.RescorerBuilder* that can be extented for custom implementation.
Is there any chance to work in *org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.RequestFactory#prepareSearchRequest* method and *org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.Query* interface to accept generic  *RescorerBuilder<RB extends RescorerBuilder>* and not only the elasticsearch provided implementation ?